# Make UISearchBar to search on two different fields

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am using a **UISearchBar** to search for certain text in the cells of a **UITableView**. I am populating the data for these cells from an array of Objects. These Objects each have three different properties, two of which are of the type `String` while the third one is `UIImage`. Is there any way I can make the UISearchBar search for text on both the text fields of the Objects without asking the user what field they wish to perform the search on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a easy way to filter your array where you could decide completely when a object of the array should be in the new array or not:

```
data = data.filter({( aObject: YourClass) -> Bool in

// code for checking if the aObject should be in the data array
// then return true if it should be in the new array and false if not
// For example your return statement could be something like this:

return (aObject.firstString.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(searchText.lowercaseString) != nil) || (aObject.secondString.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(searchText.lowercaseString) != nil)
})
```

Comment: Simple yet brilliant.. Thanks

Comment: Never even tried to think in that direction.. I was thinking of creating a new array with all the Strings in it and then link it with the original array somehow.. You saved me hours

Comment: just one question.. shouldn't that be `||` instead of `&&` ;)

Comment: Can u elaborate more? i am a beginner in Swift. i really no idea on how to do it